# How do you change the DURABILITY option on an existing memory-optimized table in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory-optimized-tables

I want to change the DURABILITY of a memory-optimized table in SQL Server 2016 from SCHEMA_AND_DATA to SCHEMA_ONLY.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) suggests that the following ALTER TABLE statement should work:

```
ALTER TABLE mem_opt_table
DURABILITY = SCHEMA_ONLY
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'DURABILITY'.
```

What is the correct syntax for changing the durability setting on a table? Are there any additional steps that I am missing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this syntax is simply incorrect. It's not something added recently for 2019 either, since this has been present for longer than that. To the best of my knowledge there is no way to alter durability; you'll need to create a new table and copy data. Maybe it's an Azure thing? (I have no instance to test with.)

Comment: Performing ALTER operations on memory-optimized tables is not supported. This includes such operations as changing the bucket_count, adding or removing an index, and adding or removing a column. This topic provides guidelines on how to update memory-optimized tables https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/altering-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver15. As a result , you can not perform this operation.

Comment: I'm confused - the first line on the page you linked says "Schema and index changes on memory-optimized tables can be performed by using the ALTER TABLE statement.". Also, why is there a [whole section on the ALTER TABLE docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax-for-memory-optimized-tables) referring specifically to ALTER TABLE statements if they are not supported?

Comment: You are so right about your considerations because there are two links about this topic in MSDN
I quoted my previous comment details from the following link for SQL 2014;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SQL/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/altering-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-2014
For SQL 2019 ;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/altering-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver15
Also, you are right about the ALTER TABLE docs questions but I don’t have any idea about it.SoI thought this option still does not provide

Comment: The syntax on webpage is faulty, there is  unclosed `[` near `| DROP
     [ { [ CONSTRAINT ][ IF EXISTS ]`. Second you could try to change that from SSMS and the use script button. The case is there is no option to change that property.

Comment: The documentation was updated for 2016 onwards to include the durability table option. Is your database in compatibility mode?

Comment: I strongly suspect it is a "typo" in documentation but don't have SQL 2016 on hand to test.The reason I think it is a typo is that durability syntax is not expanded on in the later part of the article, unlike every other option. If someone has 2016 and can test this ...

Comment: Dmitri Korotkevitch states in his book Expert SQL Server In-Memory OLTP that you cannot ALTER a MO table.https://books.google.nl/books?id=UIaQCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&dq=alter+DURABILITY+of+a+memory-optimized+table&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOpaCB69rlAhVOJ1AKHXTuDtYQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=alter%20DURABILITY%20of%20a%20memory-optimized%20table&f=false

Comment: I believe that information is probably out-of-date as of SQL Server 2016: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/altering-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-2016.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse I have just checked the compatibility level of the database, which is coming out as "130". Looking this up that refers to SQL Server 2016, so I don't think it's running in compatibility mode.

Comment: I have a question ! why do you want change Durability by Alter table ? if you already have optimize table you can remove your table and Create Again and With Create New Table Set Durability , if is this Work for you, i will  post solution in Answer ?

Comment: I could do it like this, but I'd have to reload the data in the table. The documentation says it should be possible without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation linked in the original question is faulty as was suggested by many of the comments. That is confirmed in the github issue response here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/3523#issuecomment-554511264.

Therefore, the only way to do this is to drop the table and re-create it with the desired DURABILITY setting.